# Get value of "data-..." attribute with .css selector with Scrapy

Tags: css, scrapy

I am trying to get the value of a data-attribute with scrapy:

```
response.css('.product-header-top div::attr("data-background-image")').get()
```

But I do not get the value of data-background-image and Python throws an error:

> raise SelectorSyntaxError(cssselect.parser.SelectorSyntaxError: Got
> pseudo-element
> ::FunctionalPseudoElement[::attr(['data-background-image'])] not at
> the end of a selector

Here is the relevant HTML Code of the webpage:

`<div data-background-image="/images/image.jpg" style="background-image: url(&quot;/images/image.jpg&quot;);"></div>`

Thanks

**UPDATE**
F.Hoque is right and it works fine. The website is dynamic and renders the data-background-image with JS. So the ::attr("data-...") is working. Thanks for your help @F.Hoque!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS selection is working fine. There is a typo `)`; just remove it.

```
response.css('.product-header-top div::attr("data-background-image")').get()
```

Proven by Scrapy shell:

```
In [26]:  sel.css('div::attr("data-background-image")').get()
Out[26]: '/images/image.jpg'
```

Comment: Sadly not: raise SelectorSyntaxError( cssselect.parser.SelectorSyntaxError: Expected ident or '*', got <STRING 'data-background-image' at 24>

Comment: @Waldgeist, I've updated. Now it's working fine. Thanks

Comment: Now it is not throwing an error anymore but returns None :-/ ?

Comment: Oh, thanks. I corrected the typo .. I am adding the domain in front and had to put a str() around the response.css(). Interesting that you get the image url. I still get a none when trying to get the url: print(response.css('.product-header-top div::attr("data-background-image")').get())

Comment: It's relative url  and make it absolute url by  adding domain with it, then  it will be active

Comment: As you didn't include the url , So can't make it absolute  url meaning full  image url

Comment: With this code: print(response.css('.product-header-top div::attr("data-background-image")').get())   I get a "None" response. So the value of data-background-image is not corrected properly.

Comment: Because the website is most likely dynamic and scrapy can't render js